# What is the correct value for uib-typeahead for async api that returns array of Strings?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

What is the correct value for uib-typeahead, vm.searchCompanies returns an array of Strings like ["", "aaa"]
I have the following that always dispalys No Results Found eventhough there array from the api is not empty.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label ng-i18next="candidateAdd.formerCompany"></label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control m-input" 
    ng-model="vm.candidate.former_company" 
    uib-typeahead="company for company in vm.searchCompanies($viewValue)" 
    typeahead-loading="loading" 
    typeahead-no-results="noResults" />
    <i ng-show="loading" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller method:

```
searchCompanies(keyword) {
  const self = this;
  this.ClientsService
    .searchCompanies(keyword)
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    });
}
```

Service method:

```
this.searchCompanies = function (keyword) {
  let deferred = $q.defer();
  let url = `${API_BASE_URL}/candidate/former_companies/?search=${keyword}`;

  $http.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      deferred.resolve(res.data);
    })
    .catch(res => {
      deferred.reject(res.data);
      $log.error(res.data);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: show your `vm.searchCompanies` code

Comment: @svarog I have updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: I think you are not returning the data inside your controller, should be `return this.ClientsService ...`

Comment: @svarog you are right, add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return whatever `ClientsService` gives you, otherwise you will reach the end of the function and it will return `undefined` by default.

```
vm.searchCompanies(keyword) {
  const self = this;
  return this.ClientsService
    .searchCompanies(keyword)
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    });
}
```